# Wide-to-long transformation of Javasript array using .reduce() produces empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays of objects, and I'm trying to "lengthen" it so it is just an array of objects. Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yiyupeciru/1/edit?js,console) and the code I have tried:

```
var input = [[{"text": "A", "number": 1}, {"text": "B", "number": 2},{"text": "C", "number": 3} ],
[{"text": "D", "number": 4}, {"text": "E", "number": 5},{"text": "F", "number": 6} ]]

console.log(input);
var output = input.reduce((acc,cur,i,src)=>{
      console.log(cur.length);
         acc.concat(cur);
     return acc;
  },[]);
console.log("the end");
console.log(output);
```

"input" has two subarrays of 3 objects. I want to have an array with 6 objects instead but this code is returning an empty array instead

Comment: `concat` doesn't modify in-place, you need to assign the result `acc = acc.concat(cur)` or just `return acc.concat(cur)`

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Thought it was like .push().

Comment: Btw, just `const output = input.flat();` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input = [
    [{ "text": "A", "number": 1 }, { "text": "B", "number": 2 }, { "text": "C", "number": 3 }],
    [{ "text": "D", "number": 4 }, { "text": "E", "number": 5 }, { "text": "F", "number": 6 }]
]

var output = input.reduce((acc, cur, i, src) => {
    acc.push(...cur);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```